# How to encrypt url string data in vb.net and decrypt in classic asp

Tags: vb.net, encryption, asp-classic

I'm using vb 2010 to communicate with an Classic ASP page. I'm trying to write a routine that checks the validity of the program using StreamReader, WebRequest and WebResponse

```
Dim inStream As StreamReader
    Dim webRequest As WebRequest
    Dim webResponse As WebResponse
    Dim encode As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
    Dim sURL As String = "http://localhost/activate-check.asp?"

    webRequest = webRequest.Create(sURL & "key=" & sFullKey & "email=" & txtEmail.Text)
    webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse()
    inStream = New StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream, encode)
    Dim sResponse As String = inStream.ReadToEnd()
```

The code works perfectly, but the url data is in plain text and so is the reply

```
http://localhost/activate-check.asp?key=1234567890&email=email@email.com
```

Is there a way that the request data can be encrypted and then decrypted on the asp page

Comment: You can encrypt the key *(as long as it's a cipher supported in Classic ASP)* and then base64 encode it before using it in the URL.

Comment: Thanks Lankymart, found some goods examples for base64 for vb.net and asp

Answer (score 0):

There are many valid use cases for encryption; [URL parameters is not one of them](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php).

[image: Encrypting URL parameters]

[image: What to do instead of URL parameter encryption]

If you disagree with this recommendation, make sure you're at least [using authenticated encryption](https://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken), unless you like weird exploits from chosen-ciphertext attacks.